# How to change the styling of Control Buttons in TinyMCE edior

Tags: css, button, tinymce, rich-text-editor

I am using [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/index.php) to provide rich text formatting options and I want to change the styling of the buttons in the editor. I want to make it neater like the editor that stack overflow has. Can it be done without having to write my custom TinyMCE editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define what image to use for your buttons using the [editor_css](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aeditor_css) (a tinymce init setting)

```
editor_css : '../../../js/tiny_mce/css/editor.css',
```

The css will overwrite the css used for the tinymce UI including buttons.
The default css depends on the selected mode.
Her is a part of my editor.css as example

```
.defaultSkin span.mce_delete {background:url(../../../editor/images/delete.gif)}
.defaultSkin span.mce_rename {background:url(../../../editor/images/help.gif)}
```